# Why I cannot get the value of some properties?

Tags: powershell, properties

Since I can know the `Get-Host` have some properties by

```
Get-Host|Get-Member
```

[image]

But why I cannot get it by `Get-Host.Version` or`Get-Host.UI`?And any method can help to get the item in [the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hVKgG.png) of `Get-Host` separately?

Comment: Try `(Get-Host).UI` and `(Get-Host).Version`

Comment: @LotPings Thanks very very much.But still little confusing.Why [$PSVersionTable](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4a555.png) work well?Could you give a slight explanation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Get-Host` is a cmdlet, it needs to be executed to expose the properties.
This is done with a command like this

```
PS> $var = Get-Host
PS> $var.Version
```

If you simply enter:

```
> get-host.version
```

> get-host.version : The term 'get-host.version' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
>   operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try
>   again.

That error message explains why this doesn't work.

(Parenthesis/Brackets) work just as they do in mathematics, each pair will determine the order of evaluation and return the result of the expression within. See https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html

So you have access to the methods/properties when first executing the cmdlet:

```
$tomorrow = (Get-Date).AddDays(1)
```